# A $\triangle ADE$ has $\angle AED = 120^\circ$, and $B$ and $C$ are points on $AD$ such that $\Delta BCE$ is equilateral.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, problem-solving

> A $\triangle ADE$ has $\angle AED = 120^\circ$, and $B$ and $C$ are points on $AD$ such that $\triangle BCE$ is equilateral. If $AB = 4$ cm, $CD = 16$ cm and $BC = x$ cm, find $x$ .

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

No idea for this problem. I could proceed by angle-chasing, considering $\angle BEA = \theta$ , but I don't think that will help me in finding $BC$ without Trigonometry. I think I need to use Law of Cosines on $\angle AEC$ to solve this, but I am new to it and I prefer simple geometry techniques. There are nothing I can use such as similarity, Pythagoras theorem or areas, etc.

Can anyone help me? Thank You.

Comment: Triangles ABE and ECD have the same angles. Use that similarity.

Comment: cosine formua; gives the result  easily Hint equate area of the triangle

Comment: The great thing is that I missed that simple similarity over there, @MichalAdamaszek thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Notice $\angle ECD = 120 = \angle ABE$. In $\triangle AED$, one angle is $120$ and it shares one angle each with smaller unshaded triangles.

We conclude

$$ \triangle AED \sim \triangle ABE \sim \triangle ECD$$

by AA similarity.

Thus $\triangle ABE \sim \triangle ECD$ and $$\dfrac{AB}{BE}=\dfrac{EC}{CD}$$

> $$\Rightarrow x = 8 $$

Comment: Already got it when @MichalAdamaszek pointed it out.

Comment: I didn't see his comment, but good you figured on your own.